# setting mat-option value reactive form

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular6

I am using reactive form and my form field loks like below.

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select  placeholder="Select District" formControlName="district" required>
       <mat-option
           *ngFor="let district of districts"
            [value]="district.districtID" >
           {{ district.districtID}} - {{ district.districtName}} 
       </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I am updating district field value using patchValue in activatedRoute

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(    
    params => {
         this.myForm.controls['district'].setValue(params['district']);
})
```

the problem is it is setting the value to district formcontrol,but the mat-select is still showing placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the `districtID` property as the value of your `mat-select` / `mat-option` in your template, but you are trying to bind the complete district object with `setValue`.

Change this line

```
this.myForm.controls['district'].setValue(params['district']);
```

to

```
this.myForm.controls['district'].setValue(params['district'].districtID);
```

> Check out
>   [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-khalsw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
>   stackblitz. I have commented the wrong implementation, so you can
>   easily switch between the two and see that it works if you bind the
>   `distrcitID`.